# Element attribute value is null even if the attribute has specific value

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Below is the part of html of a modal pop up in our website

```
<div id="DeliveryDateModal" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="display: block; padding-right: 17px;" aria-hidden="false">
```

If the popup is displayed the attribute `aria-hidden` value is `true` and otherwise it is `false`.

When I am trying to read the attribute value using Selenium webdriver

```
String value driver.findElement(By.id("DeliveryDateModal")).getAttribute("aria-hidden");
```

the string '`value`' is always `null`. Why is that it is null even though the attribute has a specific value

Comment: Are you sure, you are locating right element?? Verify it may be element id value is not unique and your locating other element which hasn't desire attribute. Thanks

Comment: Yes. I inspected the webpage using Firebug, I could find only one matching node with id "DeliveryDateModal" and that element has 'aria-hidden' attribute @SaurabhGaur

Comment: And in which browser you are executing selenium script??

Comment: I am currently using Google Chrome @SaurabhGaur

Comment: So you need to verify it on chrome instead of firefox, see manually same on chrome and let me know

Comment: I just tried with Google Chrome built in inspector, but got the same result @SaurabhGaur

Answer (score 0):

Try with java script.

```
String script = "return document.getElementById('DeliveryDateModal').getAttribute('aria-hidden');";
String value = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script).toString();
```